# Linux, list files being actively accessed (RW)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Is there any Linux command that can list what files are being actively accessed (actively being read/written)?

E.g., while watching a video from web browser, I want to know where the cache file being written to. Or when my `chromium-browser` starts, I want to know what files it is reading. thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list files opened by specific process, just check /proc/$PID/fd directory.

If you want to trace file operations of specific process (and it's childs) you can use strace:

```
strace -efile -f -p$PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the *lsof* command. This will list open files and what processes have them open.

[Check here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof)  for usage.